# Existence of limit cycle inside annulus via Poincaré–Bendixson

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limit-cycles

Using the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem, how I can prove that the following system of polynomial ODEs

$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{x_1}=x_1-x_2-x_1^3\\
\dot{x_2}=x_1+x_2-x_2^3
\end{aligned}$$

has one limit cycle inside the following annulus?

$$A := \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 1 < x_1^2 + x_2^2 < \sqrt{2} \right\}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495136, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057659 for very similar questions. Try to reproduce the solution methods there and come back with further questions about details or improvements.

Comment: Also nice : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267695, possible duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542261, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341603